# Como duplicar columnas de GridView

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net

Tengo un gridView de la siguiente manera:

```
<asp:GridView ID="grid" runat="server">               
            <Columns>
                <asp:BoundField HeaderText="aaa" />
                <asp:BoundField HeaderText="bbb" />
                <asp:BoundField HeaderText="ccc" />             
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
```

Se requiere que haya la opción de determinar en un dropDownList el numero de veces que se deben duplicar las columnas, en caso que se seleccione en el dropDownList el número 1 deberia duplicarse 1 vez quedando asi:

```
<asp:GridView ID="grid" runat="server">               
            <Columns>
                <asp:BoundField HeaderText="aaa" />
                <asp:BoundField HeaderText="bbb" />
                <asp:BoundField HeaderText="ccc" />
                <asp:BoundField HeaderText="aaa" />
                <asp:BoundField HeaderText="bbb" />
                <asp:BoundField HeaderText="ccc" />
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
```

en caso que se seleccione en el dropDownList el número 2 deberia duplicarse 2 veces quedando asi:

```
<asp:GridView ID="grid" runat="server">               
            <Columns>
                <asp:BoundField HeaderText="aaa" />
                <asp:BoundField HeaderText="bbb" />
                <asp:BoundField HeaderText="ccc" />
                <asp:BoundField HeaderText="aaa" />
                <asp:BoundField HeaderText="bbb" />
                <asp:BoundField HeaderText="ccc" />
                <asp:BoundField HeaderText="aaa" />
                <asp:BoundField HeaderText="bbb" />
                <asp:BoundField HeaderText="ccc" />
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
```

encontre la manera de que agrege determinado número de filas, me hace falta hacer lo mismo para las columnas.
Las filas se pueden agregar de la siguiente manera:

```
   Protected Sub Page_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        If Not Me.IsPostBack Then
            Dim dt As New DataTable()
            dt.Columns.AddRange(New DataColumn(0) {New DataColumn("aaa")})
            For j = 1 To 2
                dt.Rows.Add(j)
            Next
            ViewState("dt") = dt
            Me.BindGrid()
        End If
    End Sub

    Protected Sub BindGrid()
        grid.DataSource = TryCast(ViewState("dt"), DataTable)
        grid.DataBind()
    End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Yo lo haria en el code behind, al `gridview` le pone la propiedad autogeneratecolumns en `false`, en el evento `selectindexchanged` del `dropdown` agregaria las columnas del `gridview` dependiendo del valor seleccionado

Comment: gracias @programudo por editar no conozco aun bien las herramientas para darle un formato optimo a los mensajes